# Prove that 2 similar matrices have the same eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that

> If $B = P^{−1}AP$ and Pv is an eigenvector of A then v is an
>   eigenvector of B.

I was thinking of saying that
$$det(λI-B)=det(λI-P^{-1}AP)=det(P^{-1}λIP-P^{-1}AP)=det(P^{-1}(λI-A)P)=det(λI-A)$$
Therefore the matrices have the same eigenvalues, hence the same eigenvectors.
I'm not sure this is the right way to solve it and I'm pretty sure I'm making a mistake somewhere. Any ideas how I can solve it?

Comment: "Therefore the matrices have the same eigenvalues, hence the same eigenvectors."   You might want to check a couple of examples to test that "hence".

Comment: Are you sure you've stated the problem correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the thing to prove here is not rather "if $Pv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$" ?

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not true. But if $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$, then $Pv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the same eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $B=P^{-1}AP$ where 
\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix} &
B &=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix} &
P &=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Also note that $\displaystyle Pv=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ where $v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Is $Pv$ an eigenvector of $B$?

Note also that this example provides two similar matrices with the same eigenvalues. Do they have the same eigenvectors?

Answer (score 0):

What is true is that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, $P^{-1}v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ for the same eigenvalue:

$$B\,P^{-1}v=(P^{-1}AP)P^{-1}v=P^{-1}Av=P^{-1}\lambda v= \lambda (P^{-1}v).$$